# compare folder created timestamp with current time in ant

Tags: ant

I have script which backs up some folders before performing some another operation. I need to add some logic based on the creation time of backup folder.
I have to check if the backup folder has been created today, if yes it should skip the backup task otherwise create backup before performing next operation.

I found we can check current date/time using `tstamp` task

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
</tstamp>
```

How can I get the creation timestamp of backup folder?

And how to compare these two timestamps to check if they both are from today or different days?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to use Ant's `uptodate` task. https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html Then you can set your conditional logic inside a target that has an `if` attribute containing the property set by `uptodate`.

Comment: By _today_, do you mean _in the last 24 hours_ or really _today_, even if the script is executed one minute after midnight, ignoring the script was executed two minutes ago?

Comment: @howlger Actually it should be the same day. If I am executing on say 5 nov, I want to check if backup folder should not be created on 5 nov means same day. How to get the folder created timestamp in ant?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet execute code based on the **modification date** (which is not the same as the creation date but hopefully sufficient for your purposes) of the `backup` directory:

```
<tstamp><format property="today" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></tstamp>
<pathconvert property="todays.backup.dir">
    <dirset dir="." includes="backup">
         <date checkdirs="yes" when="after"
             datetime="${today} 00:00:00"
             pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
    </dirset>
</pathconvert>
<condition property="is.backup.required">
    <equals arg1="" arg2="${todays.backup.dir}"/>
</condition>
<sequential xmlns:if="ant:if" if:set="is.backup.required">
    <echo message="Backup..."/>
    <!-- ... -->
</sequential>
```